# Amazon AWS SSD vs EBS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I checked the other answers but still I am confused about AWS SSD vs EBS Only options during the creation of an instance.

What I read is that SSD Only actually means it is a local disk rather than a network disk. In order to add to the confusion EBS also offers SSD.

Moreover SSD Only option is supposedly volatile and gets destroyed when server is shutdown.

Am I correct so far?

I have 2 questions:

1) If I choose SSD Only option is my instance created with a volatile root drive which will be destroyed during a shutdown?

2) If so why would anybody want a volatile root device? All the installed software will be gone. What kind of scenario would benefit from a volatile root?

Answer (score 2):

You're talking about Elastic Block Store (EBS) vs Instance Store (IS).

**EBS / Network Attached Storage**

EBS is network attached storage, but that storage can be general purpose SSD, provisioned IOPS ssd, throughput optimized hard disks, or cold hard disks. Docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html).

**Instance Storage**
The instance store has disks attached to servers. Some are SATA SSD (I2), some are NVM SSD (I3), some are hard disks (Dx).

**Instance Types**

The [current generation](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) general purpose instances instances (M4 general purpose/R4 high RAM/C4 high CPU) don't have instance stores. Some of the older ones do, like C3.

T2 instances are a great general purpose instance type for varying workloads, such as public web servers or servers that are high load during the day and low load overnight. They use a credit system for access to the CPU. T2 doesn't have an instance store, it's EBS only.

There are however the I (I/O Optimized) and D (dense storage optimized) instances. They have storage directly attached to the instances. The i3 instances have nvm ssd that can do 100,000 IOPS or more. This is useful for huge databases you want to run yourself, other specialised workloads.

**Answers to your Questions**

To answer your questions:

1. If you use an instance store (I / D / F series instances) then yes, you lose your root drive on stop or terminate, but not on restart. If you choose EBS SSD then no, it's persistent disk. In either case you can take an image of the disk for backup, called a snapshot, which lets you restore quickly.
2. This is fine for caches, and distributed databases where the data exists elsewhere, or if you keep VERY good backups. Sometimes your I/O needs can't be satisfied any other way. For example a MongoDB cluster of three instances can serve an extremely high workload, and the reliability is ok since if one instance stops the other two pick it up, and may have capacity to replicate to another mirror when it comes online.

In general you should start with T instances for varying workloads like web servers, or M for constant workloads.

**Pricing Table**

The [pricing table](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/) says "EBS Only", "SSD", or "HDD". "SSD" and "HDD" are instance store.

Comment: This is not an answer for my question. First of all, in the pricing table Amazon says SSD or EBS which is a totally confusing table, no mention of instance store. Secondly question is when instance market with SSD is chosen does it make it a volatile root? And under which scenario one needs a volatile root? Not cache, not database. Root.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc AWS has many pricing tables, can you point to the specific one that's confusing you?

Comment: @ceejayoz https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/

Comment: Look at my updated question answers and pricing table section at the end.

Comment: I answered that. "SSD" or "HDD" are volatile instance store. "EBS" is the persistent network attached storage.

Comment: @CagdasOzgenc All the instances on that list use EBS for root storage. The ones that don't say "EBS Only" have **additional** local "instance" storage available. It's useful for apps that, for example, need to write and process large amounts of temporary data quickly. You might put a swap partition on 'em or something too.

Comment: @ceejayoz Ok thanks. Otherwise it would have been very stupid. Can you give a link that confirms your claim? Because once I lost an instance and was very pissed.

Comment: You can still lose instances and EBS volumes. AWS very strongly recommends treating servers as "cattle, not pets" - the loss of an instance shouldn't be a problem for your setup. You need to be able to launch a replacement for a broken instance (I suggest configuration management) and you need an effective backup strategy. Just hoping the data's always there isn't a good solution.

Comment: As for a citation, read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html

Comment: @ceejayoz Where exactly does it say that all instances have EBS as root when created?

Comment: A couple minutes in the AWS Console will verify what I'm saying. The confirmation you seek is in those docs, but it's not in a single sentence. Read up on how they treat AMI root volumes, EBS, and instance storage and you'll have your answers. Don't hesitate to just fire up an instance and test things out too.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yeah last time I fired up a spot instance like that thinking that they would just kick me out when I am outbid, but they also deleted the instance with everything in it, which was not mentioned at the time of creation. So please forgive me if I will not take the stupid engineer try and error approach. That's why I want a solid confirmation in docs.

Comment: I'd encourage you to hire a consultant, then. I've tried to impart knowledge from years of using AWS as well as references. This is where I bow out.

Comment: I think this question is done. You've been given all the information you need to answer your question, and plenty of background, but you may need to learn some more to understand it and all its implications. You need to learn more about any platform before you trust critical data to it, rather than making assumptions. Do the training at Cloud Guru if you want the information fast, or read the documentation which is free. I've read most of the documentation and done plenty of AWS training. I'm also a AWS consultant.

Comment: [Spot instance termination](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-interruptions.html). Terminate means "stop the instance and delete its resources including EBS disk". Stop means "stop, keeping resources including EBS disk". Spot instances are terminated, not stopped.

Comment: You are saying the root device will be local storage and will be destroyed when stopped, while ceejayoz claims that it will have an EBS root together with a local storage, therefore root will stay. Which one is it? For an AWS certified guy you are simply avoiding the answer.

Comment: Your questions are imprecise. The answer will vary based on the instance type you select. Spot instances can be any instance type, which can have any combination of EBS and instance storage. Either way if AWS stops your spot instance it's terminate and all disks are deleted. If you have more questions, based on the information we've provided, please ask another question. I believe your original questions have been answered, now we're just teaching you AWS.